# Trying to do simple calculation in TikZ, results in "Dimension too large." error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I am working on a pgfplot where I want to calculate some coordinate. For some reason I always get a "Dimension too large." error, but I can't figure out why since I don't understand how a overflow and/or precision error could occur since the numbers are not exceedingly big or small.

**Simply put, I want to calculate sqrt(100^2 + 500^2)**. Manually putting in the number 509.9 works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\def\Zis{500}
\def\vone{100}

%\def\va{(sqrt((\vone)^2+(\Zis)^2))}              %% Doesn't work
\pgfmathsetmacro{\va}{sqrt((\vone)^2+(\Zis)^2)}  %% Doesn't work

%\pgfmathsetmacro{\va}{509.9}          % Works
%\def\va{509.9}                       % Works

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {\va};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the number is too large for tikz, you would need the fpu library, or use the `xfp` package and then `\newcommand\va{\fpeval{sqrt(\Zis^2 + \vone^2)}}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much! Solved!

Comment: You can also use `xintexpr` package and then `\xinteval{sqrt(\vone^2+\Zis^2)}`.

Comment: You can also use in `lualatex` something like `\directlua{tex.print(math.sqrt(100^2+500^2))}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ulrike Fischer's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602973/trying-to-do-simple-calculation-in-tikz-results-in-dimension-too-large-error#comment1512321_602973) gives you the solution on how to do the calculation. To know *why* the problem occurs, this piece of the TikZ manual (around page 1011, "94. Mathematical Expressions" is the key:

[image]

...and your squared 500 is outside the range.

Obviously, you can often manipulate your expression to avoid big intermediate results (which in general is a good thing to do):

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\Zis{500}
\def\vone{100}
%% (if x>0) sqrt(x²+y²)=x·sqrt(1+(y/x)²)
\pgfmathsetmacro{\va}{\vone*sqrt(1+(\Zis/\vone)^2)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {\va};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```